# Save, Quit and Resume button in android app

Tags: javascript, android

I want to build an android quiz app with 100 questions. For every question, I have used an activity. Now I want to add a button save. When the user clicks the save button, the app must save that activity having some question. When he starts the app again and presses the resume button, the app must resume from previously saved activity, meaning from that particular question.

Comment: Have look at this answer. I believe this is what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: This site is geared to answer specific programming related questions, this question is too broad. Do you have a specific example that's not working like you want?

Comment: Use SQLite to save the questions/answers, and to load the last one. I don't think It's not a good idea to create one activity to every question. Try to create only one activity instead and load only the question text and the answers.